# Kernel Restart (Ctrl+.) in spyder not working

Tags: python, anaconda, kernel, spyder

I have recently updated my Anaconda and Spyder app! But in this new version of Spyder (version 4), when I restart the kernel (with short key and from console in above ribbon), the Restart kernel confirmation window shows up, Then I press the "yes" button but nothing happens.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please be sure to have updated to our latest version (4.1.5). That version has a lot of fixes about kernel restarts.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks for your comment. I'm already using (4.1.5) version, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Are you connecting Spyder to an external kernel? By that, I mean a kernel created outside Spyder?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba No, I haven't change the default settings in the Preferences. But I have noticed that before running any code, restarting works very well. But after running any code, it stops working!